# Как убрать кэширование IE?

Tags: codeigniter, ajax, php, smarty, кэширование

Добрый день!

Есть сайт, написан на code-igniter/smarty/ajax(jquery). 
Проблема в следующем - имеем некий текст (статью), после ее редактирования и перенаправления на просмотр открывается кэшированная версия. Помогает только ctrl+f5.

Кэширование в самом php не используется, только стандартное у smarty.
В head добавил теги:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"/> 
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"/>
```

реакции никакой.

Опыт в разработке на php 3+ лет, но с такой бедой сталкиваюсь впервые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного погуглив, я выснил, что IE кэширует Ajax-запросы к одному и тому же URL.

Предлагаются такие пути решения:

1) Через изменение настройки Ajax-запросов в jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

или

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //...
});
```

2) Путем добавления случайного динамичного параметра в запрос.